# my checkbox is not saving it's value

Tags: admin, forms

Processing the following form in the admin area, but the database constantly returning an empty cell where the info should be. Help!!

```
<form action="options.php" method="post">

            <input type="hidden" value="admin_bar" name="option_page"><input type="hidden" value="update" name="action"><input type="hidden" value="fd5754f034" name="_wpnonce" id="_wpnonce"><input type="hidden" value="/accessibilitysite/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=admin_bar&amp;settings-updated=true" name="_wp_http_referer">


            <table class="form-table">


        <tbody><tr valign="top"><th scope="row">Admin Toggle</th>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" value="admin_bar_toggle" name="admin_bar_[admin_bar_toggle]"><p>Turn Admin Bar On ?</p></td>

        </tr>   

            </tbody></table>

            <p class="submit">

            <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="button-primary">

            </p>

        </form>
```

Comment: Errmm.... `value=""`? Checkboxes still need a value.

Comment: sorry, silly mistake. It's still not saving anything useful. I know this is rookie. Sorry

Comment: As Andy has pointed out, unless the option is whitelisted, `options.php` won't save your data, typically the easiest way to whitelist an option(or set of options) is using `register_setting`, without that though your option doesn't make it past the whitelist. Andy has provided a solution for you though... :)

Comment: Silly HTML error. The problem was having a value. Removing it allowed the code to save the string "on" when the checkbox was ticked, and I can build my logic around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`options.php` does not automatically save in the database anything that you post to it. You must also tell the page which options it should look for in the posted data.

I see that you have set `option_page` to `admin_bar`, which is half of the solution. The other half is to add the option names to the whitelist. You are using the form element name `admin_bar_[admin_bar_toggle]` which will show up as `$_POST['admin_bar_']['admin_bar_toggle']` when the form is submitted with that box checked. This filter should tell `options.php` that you want this option saved:

```
function admin_page_whitelist_options( $whitelist_options ) {
    $whitelist_options['admin_bar'] = array( 'admin_bar_' );
    return $whitelist_options;
}
add_filter( 'whitelist_options', 'admin_page_whitelist_options' );
```

After that, you should find what you are looking for in the option named `admin_bar_`.

Comment: t31os correctly points to `register_setting`, which is part of a relatively new API described here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API

Comment: You may also find this tutorial useful: http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/